# None of [Index([(...column names...)], dtype='object', name='Sample Name')] are in the [index]

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like

```
Sample Name    col1    col2   col3  
     a           1       2      3
     b           4       5      6
     c           7       8      9
```

that read in from excel and then transpose it and store the transposed df at df1T. I set the index as the Sample Name so the columns are the sample names

```
dfT=df.set_index('Sample Name').T

      a    b   c
col1  1    4   7
col2  2    5   8
col3  3    6   9
```

I have a another dataframe df2 with columns a and b.

```
      a    b
row1  x    y
```

I want to add a row from df1T (ex: col1 which we can name col1) to df2 taking only the columns that are in df2 (a and b)

```
      a    b
row1  x    y
col1  1    4
```

so to do that I wrote

```
df2.loc["col1"]=df1T.loc["col1",[df2.columns]]
```

but I get the error None of the Index (column names)...are in the [index] even though df1t.columns and df2.columns shows that the column names match and are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df2.loc["col1"]=df.loc["col1",df2.columns.tolist()]
```

Output:

```
        a   b
row1    x   y
col1    1   4
```

**What was your error?**

```
[df2.columns]
```

it is a list that contains `df.columns`, but It doesn't create a list with the indexes of the columns.

```
type(df2.columns)
```

It return:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.Index
```